# Lab help for do/while

Tags: java

The following is a lab more my Intro to Java class. It's my first Java class and I'm beyond stuck. I have a few lines of code but nothing noteworthy.

Solve below problem using ‘do-while’ and random number generator.

> Simulate rolling a pair of dice 10,000 times and counts the number of times doubles of are rolled for each different pair of doubles.
>
> 1. Your program should roll two dice using the Random object (that is, generate two numbers between 1 and 6)
> 2. Define 6 counters variables
> 3. If the dice match (both should be same 1-1, 2-2, 3-3...), then increment a specific counter [you can use ‘if’ or ‘switch’ for condition check (dice1==dice2) and counter increment.
> 4. Display the results after the loop completes 10,000 times.
>
>    ```
>    1-1 displayed: 30 times 
>    2-2 displayed: 100 times 
>    ...................
>    6-6 displayed: 890 times
>    ```

Code:

```
public class DiceRoll {

    public static void main(String []args){

        int x = 0;

        int counter1 = 0;
        int counter2 = 0;
        int counter3 = 0;
        int counter4 = 0;
        int counter5 = 0;
        int counter6 = 0;

        do {

            int dice1 = (int)(Math.random()*6)-1;
            int dice2 = (int)(Math.random()*6)-1;

            if (dice1 == dice2){
                if (dice1 == 1){
                    counter1++;
                }
                if (dice1 == 2){
                    counter2++;
                }
                if (dice1 == 3){
                    counter3++;
                }
                if (dice1 == 4){
                    counter4++;
                }
                if (dice1 == 5){
                    counter5++;
                }
                if (dice1 == 6){
                    counter6++;
                }
            }

        } while (x > 10000);

        System.out.println("Results:");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("1-1 displayed: " + counter1);
        System.out.println("2-2 displayed: " + counter2);
        System.out.println("3-3 displayed: " + counter3);
        System.out.println("4-4 displayed: " + counter4);
        System.out.println("5-5 displayed: " + counter5);
        System.out.println("6-6 displayed: " + counter6);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the bit of code you have. What are you stuck on?

Comment: to be honest man, I don't really have anything for that section of the lab. I'm not sure where to start on the do-while loops

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I don't want to just give a solution, so I am going to attempt to walk you through it. (Sorry if I tell you something you already know)

**1. The Random object.** This is an instance of the Random class. You need to create a variable of type random and assign it to a Random object.

```
    Random dice = new Random();
```

Do this outside of the do-while loop, so that you aren't generating a new instance of Random and assigning the dice variable to that each time.

**2.** You are then going to need to **generate random numbers** using this object. If you look in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) you will find one method that returns an int within a user specified range:

nextInt(int bound)

To generate a random number, call this off of dice and store the return in another variable:

```
     int rollOne = dice.nextInt(6)+1;
```

The reason you are adding 1 to the answer is that nextInt returns a value between zero and the given value *exclusive*.

**3.** **The do-while loop**. This loop executes once, then checks the conditional after the while keyword before every subsequent execution (to see if it should execute again).
You need the loop to execute 10,000 times.

```
    int rolls = 0
    do { 
        rolls++;   // Increments rolls by one
    } while(rolls < 10,000);  //It starts at one, so this will loop 10,000 times
```

**4. What to put in the loop**: Every iteration, you need to roll the dice twice (use nextInt twice), compare their values, and increment the appropriate counter.

---

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now that I have seen your code, your problem is simple:

You need to increment x in the loop, perhaps right after the

```
     do {
```

line. You also need to edit the conditional in the while part. It should be

```
    } while (x < 10000); //Less than, not greater than >
```